# Use Hanner inequality to prove the $L^p$ space is uniformly convex for $1<p<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ be a measure space, and $f,g\in L^p(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$. I know that the Hanner inequality is following:
$$\|f+g\|_{L^p}^p+\|f-g\|_{L^p}^p\geq (\|f\|_{L^p}+\|g\|_{L^p})^p+|\|f\|_{L^p}-\|g\|_{L^p}|^p$$
for $1\leq p\leq 2$, and the equality is reversed for $2\leq p<\infty$. Now I want to use the equality to prove $L^p(X)$ is uniformly convex for  $1<p<\infty$, I can prove the case in which $2\leq p<\infty$, but in the case $1\leq p\leq 2$, the equality is reversed, I have no idea how to start?

Comment: This said $infinity$ on the main page, like that, I came here to edit and now it is correct but it doesn't say "last edited" - WITCHCRAFT!

Comment: OMG! I'm precognitive.

Comment: You may want to start from your definition of uniform convexity. Is it in the following form? For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that if $||x||,||y||\leq 1$ and $||x-y||\geq\varepsilon$ then $||x+y||\leq 2(1-\delta(\varepsilon))$?

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, I don't know how to bound $\|f+g\|_{L^p}$ when $1\leq p\leq 2$.